Turn off distracting popups in iterm2
When I'm typing in iterm2, there are occasionally popups and other similar visual distractions. One particularly intrusive one pops up image links every time I press the command key.
Generally speaking, the only thing I want an application like iterm2 to display, is what I am explicitly typing.
I've waded through the rather bewildering range of preferences for iterm2, but can't find what features are in play.
Any ideas?

Can you add a screen grab of this

@MarcWilson Yes, I think for 99.9% of users, Terminal is the better option. The only thing I like about iTerm is that it has an option for tabs on the side. Sadly, it doesn't do a good job of it, since there's no way to control the size of the tabs, the font, the background color, etc., so the visibility and usability are mediocre. I'd be pleased as punch if Apple's, or some other terminal emulator, did a good job with side tabs.
